# Sending a GCM message (server-side) often fails - but far from always

Tags: android, .net, http, google-cloud-messaging

I am using the Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) service for my Android app. I have implemented it according to all the rules, and it works. Well, almost.

Most often, I'd say in 60-70% of the cases I can successfully send a GCM message from my server, using the webservice as discussed on google webpages.

Normally, I get the following reply from the webservice, which indicates that I successfully sent the GCM message:

```
{
    "multicast_id":8378088572050307085,
    "success":1,
    "failure":0,
    "canonical_ids":0,
    "results":
    [
        {
            "message_id":"0:1363080282442710%7c4250c100000031"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is saying: all OK, message sent.

However, in many cases I get a HTTP error when calling the webservice, that says:

> Unable to read data from the transport connection: An established
>   connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.

This is the .NET message to tell me that calling a webservice (using HttpWebRequest and POST) failed.

This is some log messages that shows the problem:

[image]

This is the code I am using for calling the WS:

```
public static string SendMessage(string registrationId, string command, string extra, bool retry)
{
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
        request.Method = PostWebRequest;
        request.KeepAlive = false;

        GCMPostPacket json = new GCMPostPacket()
        {
            collapse_key = "1",
            time_to_live = 60,
            registration_ids = new List<string>(new string[] { registrationId }),
            data = new GcmData()
            {
                message = command,
                misc = extra
            }
        };
        // Converting to JSON string
        string jsonString = SICJsonProtocol.JSONHelper.Serialize<GCMPostPacket>(json);
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString);

        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;

        request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "key=" + "MyVerySecretKey");

        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();

        using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            HttpStatusCode responseCode = ((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusCode;
            if (responseCode.Equals(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized) || responseCode.Equals(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unauthorized - need new token");
            }
            else if (!responseCode.Equals(HttpStatusCode.OK))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Response from web service not OK :");
                Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
            }

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            string responseLine = reader.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("************************");
            Console.WriteLine("GCM send: " + responseCode + " | " + responseLine);
            // This is the log shown in the image above
            SRef.main.gui.ServiceUpdate("GCM send: " + responseCode + " | " + responseLine);
            reader.Close();
            response.Close();
            return responseLine;
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // This is the log shown in the image above
        SRef.main.gui.ServiceUpdate("Failed send GCM, " + (retry ? "retrying in 20 sec" : "not retrying") + ". Error=" + e.Message);
        if (retry)
        {
            System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate(object obj)
            {
                try
                {
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20000);
                    SendMessage(registrationId, command, extra, false);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                }
            });
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Can anyone see if I am doing something wrong, or if I am missing something in general?

Comment: Is it possible to log the value of `e` inside the outer catch-block? It might contain useful informtation.

Comment: Sure, I will add that, and see if it helps

Comment: Actually, it is already there. e.Message is written in the output, thats the error message u see there... *+ ". Error=" + e.Message);*

Answer (score 3):

> Unable to read data from the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.

This error has nothing to do with GCM API in particular. It means that your client tried to contact the web service but the connection that was established has been severed in one of the network layers. Depending on where you get this error and the error message it could mean several things.

1. Your client decided to abort the connection due to a socket timeout. Increase the client read / socket timeout to improve the situation.
2. A load balancer that sits between the client and the server dropped the connection. Each party thinks that the other one dropped the connection.

Network timeouts are usually a huge pain since it is never clear where the connection was dropped and who dropped it. If increasing timeouts does not help I'd suggest sending the requests through a proxy that can sniff the HTTPS traffic (charles / TCPMON) or using Wireshark to see which packets are being dropped.

Your android app also has GCM monitoring that you can enable on the Statistics tab. Check if the GCM API reports a status message other than 200 OK on that graph. That will help narrow down the problem further. If there are no reports of status codes other than 200, it means GCM never got your API requests to begin with.

Comment: I know its a network problem, but its not a general network problem as I am always connected to the Internet (otherwise I wouldnt have connection to the outside world etc). Its something specific between my server and gcm-servers. And it's the same problem if I run it on another computer or locally.

Comment: Statistics tab? Where is this?

Comment: Once you link your [sender ID on the console](http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2663268?hl=en) you should start seeing the GCM response code status. Go to your app -> Statistics -> Select GCM messages from the drop down -> Click on the 'GCM response code' tab.

Comment: Always being connected to the internet does not help do away with the drop in connections. I agree that it has something to do with the connection between your servers and the GCM servers. If it helps I've seen connections like these dropped due to |1| -> Load balancers (LB) running out of memory |2| -> LB dropping connections arbitrarily |3| -> Bad timeout settings. You will still need a network trace to zero in on the problem.

Comment: same problem is happening with me. GCM is working good but my client app request gets failed ,i am sending request using volley library and its giving TimeOutError. I tried using setRetryPolicy method of volley but still request gets fails. Can you tell me any efficient way to do it ??
How whatsapp manages all these things ? How their request never get timeout ?